# get_post_meta() returns empty

Tags: wordpress, translation, shortcode

I'm doing a basic shortcode for translating a text in the footer of a wordpress site, and I'm using the get_post_meta() for identifing the language in a meta tag (which I'm adding with a plug in for inserting html code in the header) but it returns empty I'm wondering if this is because the plugin and the order in which he creates the elements(first he executes my shortcode and then the plugin) or if it is something else.

```
function text_Footer($atts, $content=null){ 

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'id' => ''
    ), $atts));
    $ID = get_the_ID();
     $lang = get_post_meta(ID,'language',true);
    if($lang == 'portuguese')
    {
    $output='<p>Text in portuguese</p>';
    }
    else
    {
    //echo $lang."nope";
    $output = '<p>Text in spanish</p>';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: There are few problems here, like the `ID` part in `get_post_meta(ID,'language',true);`, don't use `extract` and it's not clear what post object you're trying to target here.

Answer (score 0):

get_the_ID() function must be within The Loop.
if you want to extract id from shortcode, just need to use it in write way: `$lang = get_post_meta($id,'language',true);`